# cakekphp 3: Generating link to current page with language parameter

Tags: url, cakephp, parameters, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I feel this should be really simple, but I can't make it work.
I want to create a link to the current page, whatever that might be, and simple change the "lang" parameter. Basically to have a link in the corner that changes language but leaves you on the same page.

My best attempt yet is this:

```
//current url: 'da/articles/view/1'
$this->Url->build(['lang' => 'en']);
//returns '/en/articles/view'
```

So, how do I get it to retain the passed param 1, which of course is the id of the article? Mind you, I have other controllers for which I would like this to work so simply doing this won't do, although it works:

```
$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view', 1, 'lang' => 'en']);
```

Answer (score 0):

When generating URLs, the router will by default only automatically populate the `plugin`, `controller` and `action` keys (also `_ext` but that's not overly relevant here).

You have two additional route elements, `lang` and `id` (I'll just assume that its named `id`), so passing only one of them (`lang`) will not work, it will match a different route (one where `id` isn't defined).

You can solve this by for example persisting the `id` and/or `lang` elements, that's what the `persist` option is there for:

```
Router::scope('/', function (\Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect(
        '/:lang/:controller/:action/:id',
        [],
        [
            'lang' => 'da|en',
            'pass' => [
                'lang',
                'id'
            ],
            'persist' => [
                'lang',
                'id'
            ]
        ]
    );
});
```

That way the specified `lang` and `id` keys will be populated with the values from the URL in case they haven't explicitly been passed, allowing you to generate URLs by passing only one of them (given that the current URL matches the route that persists these elements of course).

Similar results can be achieved using URL filters (they apply globally though), which currently is the only way documented in the Cookbook. The `persist` option was probably forgotten after [**it had been reintroduced**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/6081) (originally it had been removed for 3.0).

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Routing\RouteBuidler::connect()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#_connect)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating Persistent URL Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-persistent-url-parameters)**

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned I have multiple controllers and they may have varying parameters, so I really need to be able to use this with a basic routing like this:
     $routes->connect('/:action/*');

Comment: @JonasKvistJensen Your "basic routing" example doesn't have any of the route elements that you've shown in your question... you also didn't mention arbitrary parameters, only other controllers, which would be covered by the example in my answer. You may want to update your question with proper context to better reflect your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using this solution, which works. But it seems like there should be a simpler way:

```
$current_url = Router::parse($this->request->here);
unset($current_url['plugin']);
unset($current_url['_matchedRoute']);
foreach($current_url['pass'] as $pass)
    $current_url[] = $pass;

unset($current_url['pass']);

foreach($langs as $key => $lang){
    $current_url['lang'] = $key;
    echo $this->Html->tag('li', $this->Html->link($lang, $current_url));       
}
```